# Video app for Samba

Tags: android, samba

I have setup a samba server on my router.
And I'm sharing some videos with people and I don't want them deleting them.
I tried setting server to readonly but then my current Samba app ask the user for username and password.

I need a app that supports samba (smb) and doesn't allow user to rename or delete files( even thought the server is write able) .

Comment: Isn't that rather a question of configuring the Samba server? Grant public access read-only (or have a user that has only read access) for your users, and another one with full access for you? Then you give the credentials of the read-only account to your users, and keep the other one to yourself. The Android app itself cannot change that, and to my knowledge there isn't any app for read-only access (and if there were, your users could simply use another one then).

Comment: the samba settings on my NETGEAR router are very limited. I tried setting readonly but all the clients ask for admin password for read/write

Comment: OK, so you basically want a Sambe client that *accepts* if the connection is read-only, and doesn't try to "enforce write mode". What other features should it have? Are you looking for a file manager that can deal with Samba shares? Or should it rather be a "sync service"? Or a video player? Must it be free, or is there any budget?

Comment: It would be great if it could play videos. If possible free

Comment: OK – so may I suggest you [edit] your question accordingly to make that clear? I.e. instead of "Android app for Samba", something like "Video player for Android supporting Samba" (title), and in the body pointing out your users should just be able to play those videos, and the app should preferably be free?

Comment: Pointers: My list of Android [Video-Player](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_player)s. Some of them support Samba, e.g. [BUZZ](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bugunsoft.BUZZPlayer). Also, some [file managers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman#group_156) have built-in support for Samba and video playing.

Comment: I checked out BUZZ Player and it has a feature to disable file deletion from servers great app.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Made that an answer then. If you "accept" it (tick the check-mark next to the answer post) you'd mark that as working (and preferred) solution, so people looking for something similar can see its existence even from lists. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at **[BUZZ Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bugunsoft.BUZZPlayer),** which has built-in support for a lot of networking stuff:

[image: BUZZ] [image: BUZZ]
<sup>*BUZZ Player* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bugunsoft.BUZZPlayer); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As a video player is not supposed to "write" video files, it should not complain on read-only connections. The app also has an option to turn off deletion from servers (to avoid accidental removal of files).

*BUZZ* can play audio and video from network server directly, and supports a variety of formats, plus it can deal with resolutions up to full HD. It features a built-in network browser, and even allows you to control playback speed (from slow-motion 0.5X to fast-motion 4X). Sounds like a good match for your needs.